# Align environment: page break AND reset alignment

Tags: align, page-breaking

I have an `align` environment shown below, and have enabled `\allowdisplaybreaks`, which works as I expected. However, in the example below, I don't want the blue box to remain aligned with the red box; I'd prefer if the blue box is aligned independently of the red box, since it's on a different page.

How can I accomplish this without manually creating a new align environment for the red box?

[image: 1]

---

[image: 2]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

Now take the left hand side, and consider the following manipulations:
    \begin{align*}
        n! \cdot \left| e - e_n \right|
            &= n! \cdot \left| \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} - \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \right| \\
        &= n! \cdot \left| \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \right| \\
        &= \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \frac{n!}{k!} \\
        &= \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n + j)!} &&\text{(let $j = k - n$)} \\
        &= \frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{(n + 2)(n + 1)} + \frac{1}{(n + 3)(n + 2)(n + 1)} + \cdots \\
        &\leq \frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)^3} + \cdots
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give a `MWE`. We are not expected to retype everything

Comment: @Denis I have added some code.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot add much to mico's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see how you may achieve your objective without creating, one way or another, two separate and independent `align*` environments.

I have a different suggestion, though. I start by noting that you're currently placing the `\text{(let $j = k - n$)}` explanatory aside so far to the right of the rest of the material, that it pushes all remaning material far to the left. I suggest you replace `&&\text{(let $j = k - n$)}` with, say, `\qquad\qquad\text{(let $j = k - n$)}`. This will allow the entire rest of the `align*` environment shift quite a bit to the right, making the entire expression look far more centered. The upshot, in my view, is that with this adjustment, it's no longer necessary to think about providing separate alignment points for the first two rows and the final four rows.

I would also replace `\left|` and `\right|` with `\biggl|` and `\biggr|`, respectively. That way, the absolute-value bars don't look nearly so dominant.

[image]

Comment: Replacing with `\qquad` spacing didn't really help very much, to my eyes; I think I will just split it into two separate `align*` environments. But thanks for the suggestion for the absolute value signs!